# textfield inputs range in interface builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have multiple textfields in my nib file.
I want to decide the input range in my one textfield to 6-16 digits and I don't want to change any other textfield input. For that I made a method called tflimit as below.

```
-(IBAction)tflimit:(id)sender
{      
    if([textfields1.text length]>=15 )
    {
         [textfields1 resignFirstResponder]; 
    }   
}
```

With this method I can input only 16 digits input.
How can I decide the range(6-16) of an input in the textfield without changing other codes.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter user input in `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method in text field delegate:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if (textField == textfields1){// Apply logic only to required field
        NSString* newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        return [newString length] < 16 && [newString length] > 5;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Note that to work correctly this method require textfield to be pre-populated with text at least 5 characters long.

Comment: thnks for ur reply..but i have to input from keyboard without populating any prior input.and for implemnting this method i have to declare the <UITextFieldDelegate> in .h file.and for implementing this method my all fields are not responded.how to do perform my task.please help me .

Comment: To avoid pre-populating you must add extra logic for checking minimum text length - e.g. check for that case only in case characters are being deleted (that is when replacementString is empty). To make that work your controller must conform to UITextFieldDelegate protocol, but sorry don't understand what problem you have with that.